# Why is ember.js or backbone.js used?

Tags: backbone.js

I have been trying to go through ember.js and backbone.js. I am very new to these things. I am trying to figure out why exactly are these things used? Are they some frameworks? Or is it something like jquery?

Answer (score 3):

> Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models
>   with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API
>   of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and
>   connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.

Guess where I found this?

Answer (score 1):

They are javascript MVC frameworks designed to more easily separate different functionalities in client side web applications. They offer the basic methodology of separating program functionalities according to the [Model-View-Controller](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html) concept. They deal with the structure of your program, wherein jQuery abstracts some of javascript's more useful functionality into a form that is more easily digestible and generally makes code shorter and more readable.

This was the short answer, for the long answer I suggest frantic googling.

Comment: I'd suggest googling even for the short answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

See here for comparison:
http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/